# can't installing tensorflow in pycharm

Tags: python, tensorflow

So I am trying to install tensorflow for my pycharm to start learning Machine Learning, but I have been struggling for over 3 days trying to install it, and was wondering if anyone could help me. Also, I have a question: Do I need Anaconda in order to install tensorflow, and if yes, then how do I get it for an earlier version of python because I can only get it for python 3.8, which I heard isn't compatible with tensorflow yet. Please help! Also, everytime I try to install tensorflow it says:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.5
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow, i have aready tried in pycharm going to the python interpreter and installing 2.4.0 it keeps giving me the same error as always

Comment: which operating system are you using. you don't need Anaconda  but it will make it simpler

Comment: I am on windows

Comment: Python 3.8 is compatible with Tensorflow:  it's the current newest version, Python 3.9, that isn't. You don't need Anaconda, and it seems you're trying to force it to install the version 1.5 while you want a more recent one. You may want `tensorflow==2.4.0` instead, or just `tensorflow` to let it decide the version.

Comment: i have aready tried in pycharm going to the python interpreter and installing 2.4.0 it keeps giving me the same error as always -- @OctaveL

Comment: @Tylers77 How could it give you the exact same error if it's not the same version? What's the error message exactly, and how are you installing more precisely?

Comment: This is the error: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Comment: i have tried updating pip, uninstalling and reinstalling different versions of python ranging from 3.6 to 3.8, and installing different versions of tensorflow, and I also did all of this while swapping on and off anaconda – OctaveL

Comment: ^^^^^^^^ @OctaveL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/1.5.1/#files

[image]

so you wanna install specific tf version?

Download .whl file then using `pip install path/to/file.whl`.

tensorflow==1.5.1 is compatible this list versions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I recommend :

1. Install Anaconda
   [Anaconda Individual Edition](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual)

2. Open Anaconda Navigator
3. Create a new environment called "tf". I had issues in one of my machines using python 3.8 with tf, i recommend to use python 3.7
4. Still on the navigator screen, selected "Not Installed" on the dropdown and type "tensorflow" on the search box next to the dropdown. Install tensorflow on your tf environment.
5. open the command line and use : conda activate ft

It looks like a lot but it takes a few minutes. Then, in PyCharm, you can just select your conda environment.

I was a bit disappointed that PyCharm does not support jupyter notebooks anymore in the Community Edition so I decided to switch to Visual Studio Code. You should check it out. It is super easy and tons of plug-ins.